# Relation between Using Heine-Borel Theorem and Axiom of Choice

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
$\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\realset}{\mathbb{R}}$

I am using the Heine-Borel theorem to prove the following proposition: if a function $f$ is continuous on a compact interval $I$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$. I doubted if it is legitimate to assert the existence of a function at the start of the proof.

The Heine-Borel theorem states that if $\mathcal{H}$ is an open covering for a compact set $I$, then there is a $\widetilde{\mathcal{H}}$ such that $\widetilde{\mathcal{H}} \approx n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\widetilde{\mathcal{H}} \subseteq \mathcal{H}$ and $\widetilde{\mathcal{H}}$ is an open covering of $I$. Below is the starting point of the proof.

Suppose $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ and $t_{0} \in \left[a,b\right]$. Since $f$ is continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$, there exists some $\delta_{0}$ such that if $x_{0} \in \left(t_{0} - 2\delta_{0}, t_{0} + 2\delta_{0}\right) \cap \left[a,b\right]$, then
\begin{equation}
\abs{f\left(x_{0}\right) - f\left(t_{0}\right)} < \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}
\end{equation}
Generalizing the above statement, for any $\epsilon > 0$, for any $t \in \left[a,b\right]$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in \left(t - 2\delta,t + 2\delta\right) \cap \left[a,b\right]$, $\abs{f\left(x\right) - f\left(t\right)} < \epsilon / 2$. Thus, there exists an interval function $I: \left[a,b\right] \to \powerset{\realset}$ defined on $\left[a,b\right]$ such that for any $t \in \left[a,b\right]$, there exists $\delta_{t} > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
I_{t} = \left(t - \delta_{t}, t + \delta_{t}\right),
\end{equation}
and for any $\epsilon > 0$, for any $x \in I_{t} \cap \left[a,b\right]$, $\abs{f\left(x\right) - f\left(t\right)} < \epsilon / 2$, and
\begin{equation}
\left[a,b\right] \subseteq \bigcup_{t\in\left[a,b\right]}I_{t}.
\end{equation}

I am a little skeptical about the existence of function $I$, as there exists such an interval $I_{t}$ for any $t\in \left[a,b\right]$ does not mean the function $I$ exists. It seems to me that the argument is related to axiom of choice in set theory, as the axiom is introduced with the background that construction of function is needed when there exists an object for every point of a set while the object cannot be uniquely determined. Is it also a scenario where axiom of choice is needed to argue the existence of such a function?

Comment: This is not strictly related to the question, but you are using a nonstandard definition of “compact”. The usual definition is actually the conclusion of the Heine-Borel theorem (so it looked to me like you were proving that a compact space is compact). You are likely referring to a closed and bounded set, and in metric spaces other than $\mathbb{R}^n$, it’s common to find closed, bounded subspaces which are not compact (in the usual sense that every open cover has a finite subcover). You should be aware of this if you learn general topology or switch texts in analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom of choice is not needed here. While it is true that in general to go from "$\forall \mathcal{X}\exists \mathcal{Y}\theta(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$" to "$\exists\mathscr{F}\forall\mathcal{X}\theta(\mathcal{X},\mathscr{F}(\mathcal{X}))$" we need the axiom of choice, we rarely in practice actually need to appeal to this general principle.

In this case, note that $I$ is in fact determined by the function $t\mapsto\delta_t$; moreover, there's no reason *not* to have each $\delta_t$ be a positive rational. Now we can fix ahead of time a well-ordering $\trianglelefteq$ of the positive rationals, and consider the explicitly-defined function sending $t$ to the $\trianglelefteq$-least positive rational with the appropriate properties. This doesn't require choice at all.

(In general, arguments in classical analysis tend not to require choice due to the second-countability of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Can positive rational numbers be well ordered?

Comment: @ZiqiFan Yes. For example (looking at the rationals in $(0,1]$ only for simplicity): $${1\over 1},\quad{1\over 2},\quad {1\over 3}, {2\over 3}, \quad{1\over 4}, {3\over 4},\quad {1\over 5},{2\over 5}, {3\over 5}, {4\over 5}, \quad...$$ (the pattern should be clear).

Comment: I was thinking well ordering means every non-empty subset is of a least element.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Yes. What I've indicated is an ordering of the rationals in $(0,1]$ which has the same ordertype as $\mathbb{N}$. This is well-ordered. For example, if we call the ordering above "$\trianglelefteq$," the $\trianglelefteq$-least element of $(0,1]$ which is less than ${1\over 3}$ in the usual sense is ${1\over 4}$.

Comment: I see. Ordering doesn't always suggest the common sense of "smaller than".

Comment: Could you let me know the so-called second-countability?

Comment: @ZiqiFan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space